# Optimize sql query that queries the same XML multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

After setting the value of @temp1, I was told that I can optimize these queries into a SELECT statement retrieving 2 values, instead of having "repeated access to XML".

```
DECLARE @temp1 XML
DECLARE @exec_gadget_config XML
DECLARE @exec_client_name_index NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @exec_client_number_index NVARCHAR(500)

SELECT @temp1 = '<gadget name="EYDocuments">                
                    <drawer id="0000000002">
                        <otherColumns>
                            <col id="000000000B" name="Client Name"  />
                            <col id="000000000C" name="Client Number"  />
                        </otherColumns>
                    </drawer>
                </gadget>'

SELECT @exec_client_number_index = (
        SELECT @temp1.value('(//drawer[@id="0000000002"]/otherColumns//col[@name="Client Name"]/@id)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(500)')
        )

SELECT @exec_client_name_index = (
        SELECT @temp1.value('(//drawer[@id="0000000002"]/otherColumns//col[@name="Client Number"]/@id)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(500)')
        )

SELECT @exec_client_number_index, @exec_client_name_index
```

1. Is that possible?
2. My proposed response to that question is below. Does this remove the "repeated access to XML"?
3. If not, how can I do so?

space

```
SELECT @exec_client_number_index = (
        SELECT @temp1.value('(//drawer[@id="0000000002"]/otherColumns//col[@name="Client Name"]/@id)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(500)')
        ), @exec_client_name_index = (
        SELECT @temp1.value('(//drawer[@id="0000000002"]/otherColumns//col[@name="Client Number"]/@id)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(500)')
        );
```

Comment: you're using sub-selects, so you're STILL doing "repeated access to XML". each of those subqueries is going to be parsed/executed separately.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without "repeated access to XML"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
DECLARE @temp1 XML
SELECT @temp1 = '<gadget name="EYDocuments">                
                            <drawer id="0000000002">
                                <otherColumns>
                                    <col id="000000000B" name="Client Name"  />
                                    <col id="000000000C" name="Client Number"  />
                                </otherColumns>
                            </drawer>
                        </gadget>'

SELECT
    a.b.value('@id', 'varchar(10)') value
FROM
    @temp1.nodes('/gadget/drawer/otherColumns/col') a(b)
```

**Output**

```
value
----------
000000000B
000000000C
```

Comment: 'a' looks like a table alias. If so, what is (b)?

Comment: @Hoppe: Actually syntax of **nodes** is `nodes (XQuery) as Table(Column)`, it means `a(b)` is the table name and column name for the resulting rowset.

Comment: I added an order by statement so that I can determine which is which. Thanks! SELECT
 a.b.value('@id', 'varchar(10)') attr_id,
 a.b.value('@name', 'varchar(20)') attr_name
FROM
 @temp1.nodes('/gadget/drawer/otherColumns/col') a(b)
ORDER BY attr_name